# App name taken on App Store, how can I find developer if no App exists

Tags: app-store, naming

I'm about to submit my first app to the App Store, but the name is already taken. I've searched the App Store, but I can't find any app by that name. I'm guessing Apple removed it after no update to Binary after 120 days.

How can I find details of this developer, so that I can ask him to delete the app? And even if he does, will that name then become available again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the 120 Day limit was reached on the store the name would be available for use. My guess is that someone has the name registered and is still within the 120 day limit.

If you hold a copyright or trademark for the name of your app, you can attempt to contact apple to see if they can do anything for you. There is no way to search for apps that arent published to the App Store.